# Pegando id errado ao selecionar linha com CheckBox

Tags: php, mysql

Nesse script abaixo eu faço um loop em linhas de uma tabela, aonde contém em cada linha um checkbox e inputs ocultos.

O problema é que quando eu seleciono umas linhas com o checkbox, os valores correspondentes ao checkbox vem correto mais os outros inputs vem como pegando dados das linha não marcadas

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

teste.php

```
<form id="form2" name="form2" action="acao.php form=cotacao" method="POST">
<table>    
<tr>
<td><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="<?echo $id_produtos>"/>  
</td>
<td><?echo $id_produtos?></td>
<td><input type="hidden" name="nome[]"  value="<?echo $nome?>" /></td>
<td><input type="hidden" name="tipo_serv[]"  value="<?echo $tipo_serv?>" />  
</td>
<td><input type="hidden" name="valor[]"value="<?echo $valor?>" />  
</td> 
</tr><input type="submit" value="Gerar"/>
```

acao.php

```
    if (isset($_POST['checkbox'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['checkbox'] as $key => $value) {
    echo $id_saida = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
         $tipo = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tipo_serv'][$key]);
    echo $nome = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nome'][$key]);
         $start = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['start'][$key]);
    echo $valor = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['valor'][$key]);
         $desconto = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['desconto'][$key]);
        $tipo_veiculo=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tipo_veiculo'[$key]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para fazer a relação utilizando o campo `id`, o atributo *name*, que tem como valor `checkbox[]`, deve possuir como índice o valor da `id` de modo a poderes ler e assinar os valores corretos com o `foreach`.

No teu script deves simplesmente imprimir um `echo` como índice para a tua array `checkbox[]`, esse índice deve ser o mesmo para o atributo `name` do produto. No teu caso, seria algo assim:

```
checkbox[<?php echo $id_produtos; ?>]
```

Abaixo outro exemplo de como ficaria, com base num script montado à parte:

```
<?php

// Ler dados enviados pelo formulario gerado
if(isset($_POST["enviar"])){
    foreach($_POST["checkbox"] as $key=>$value){        
        echo "ID: " . $id . " Nome: " . $_POST["nome"][$key] . "<br/>";
    }    
}


// Conexao
// Eu usei uma tabela local para elaborar este exemplo
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "example");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM jogos";
$form = null;

if($query = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)){
    while($linha = mysqli_fetch_object($query)){
        $form .= "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"checkbox[{$linha->id}]\" value=\"{$linha->id}\"/>{$linha->nome}<br/>";    
        $form .= "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"nome[{$linha->id}]\" value=\"{$linha->nome}\"/>";
    }    
    
    // Montar o resto do formulário
    
    ?>
    <hr>
    <form method="POST" action="">
    <!-- Resto !-->
    <?php echo $form; ?>
    <!-- Resto !-->
    <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="enviar"/>
    </form>
    
    <?php
}

?>
```

Outra coisa é que  não entendi exatamente como está estruturado esse teu script, visto que numa parte esta relacionado a automóveis e noutra simplesmente não sei do que se trata. Foi esta uma das razões pelas quais tive de elaborar um exemplo próprio.

Outra recomendação é em relação as funções **MySQL** que estão **depreciadas**, utilize **MySQLi** ou **PDO** em vez dela.

---

## Referências:

[PDO - PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

[MySQLi - PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: Ola Amigo desculpa a minha ignorância , mais não consegui adaptar  no meu codigo, to colocando aqui https://3v4l.org/L79GG    ,     https://3v4l.org/L2SoW  o codigo real como uso hoje

Comment: O teu código é demasiado extenso, por essa mesma razão isolei e respondi a pergunta com base num exemplo que fiz. Mas a implementação no teu não deve ser difícil, onde tens os atributos `name="nome[]"`, `name="tipo_serv[]"`, `name="id_produto[]"` e outros, basta colocares `<?echo $id_produtos?>` como índice nos atributos `name`, da seguinte forma: `name="tipo_serv[<?echo $id_produtos?>]"`, e assim sucessivamente.

Comment: Ola Amigo fiz como sugerido mais no quando le so vem o id do checkbox. to fazendo assim https://3v4l.org/muCMG

Comment: Olha, experimenta isto: https://3v4l.org/ErSeU

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi direito, você quer enviar múltiplas linhas, certo? Da forma como você está fazendo só está enviando um form, pois você está colocando um form para cada linha, acho que o seguinte pode ajudar:

```
<form id="form2" name="form2" action="acao.php form=cotacao" method="POST">
<table>
<?php
$cmd = "SELECT * FROM produtos where id_transfer = '$id_transfer' AND   
tipo_serv <> 'Regular'  ";

    $produtos = mysql_query($cmd);
    $total = mysql_num_rows($produtos);
    while ($linha = mysql_fetch_array($produtos)) {

 $id_produtos = $linha['id_produtos'];
 $nome = $linha['nome'];
 $valor = $linha['valor'];
 $tipo_serv = $linha['tipo_serv'];
 ?>
<tr>
<td><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="<?echo $id_produtos>"/>  
</td>
<td><?echo $id_produtos?></td>
<td><input type="hidden" name="nome[]"  value="<?echo $nome?>" /></td>
<td><input type="hidden" name="tipo_serv[]"  value="<?echo $tipo_serv?>" />  
</td>
<td><input type="hidden" name="valor[]"value="<?echo $valor?>" />  
</td> 
</tr><input type="submit" value="Gerar"/>   
<?php}?>
</table>
</form>
```